# Extract values from H mn s format time in python

Tags: python, regex, time

I want to extract this kind of data from a time value with some regex:

```
1h 34mn 2s     >>> [1,34,2]
1h 4mn         >>> [1,4]
34mn 2s        >>> [34,2]
34s            >>> [34]
```

I tryed :

```
re.match(r'((.*)h)?((.*)mn)?((.*)s)?', '1h 34mn').groups()
('1h', '1', ' 34mn', ' 34', None, None)
```

Almost done but still not what I'm looking for.

Edit:

I need to extract total value in seconds `1h 34mn 2s >>> 1*3600+34*60+2`

Comment: Yes, thanks last one was typo, corrected now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if all you just want is seconds, and aren't too worried that hours precedes minutes, and minutes precedes seconds, as long as they're qualified (ie, '1s 9h 32m' is valid), you could use:

```
import re

mult = {'h': 60*60, 'mn': 60}
res = sum(int(num) * mult.get(val, 1) for num, val in re.findall('(\d+)(\w+)', '1h 34mn 2s'))
# 5642
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data is as in your example, you can simply do:

```
In [171]: import re

In [172]: s='1h 34mn 2s'

In [173]: re.findall('\d+',s)
Out[173]: ['1', '34', '2']
```

or if you want `int`'s:

```
In [175]: [int(i)for i in re.findall('\d+',s)]
Out[175]: [1, 34, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[in] regex = re.compile(r'^(?:(\d+)h)?(?: *)(?:(\d+)mn)?(?: *)(?:(\d+)s)?$')
[in] for x in ("1h 34mn 2s", "1h 4mn", "34mn 2s", "34s"):
[in]     hours, minutes, seconds = regex.match(x).groups()
[in]     total = 0
[in]     if hours:
[in]         total += int(hours) * 3600
[in]     if minutes:
[in]         total += int(minutes) * 60
[in]     if seconds:
[in]         total += int(seconds)
[in]     print total

[out] 5642
[out] 3840
[out] 2042
[out] 34
```

Just realized you weren't looking for a triple on every input.  Fixed now.

Comment: thanks but I just realised I need to convert the values to seconds so I need to identify them first (mn * 60, h *3600)

Answer (score 0):

KISS

```
import re

a = ['1h 34mn 2s','1h 4mn','34mn 2s','34s']

def convert(s):
    if s:
        return int(s[0])
    else:
        return 0

def get_time(a):
    h = convert(re.findall('(\d*)h',a))
    m = convert(re.findall('(\d*)m',a))
    s = convert(re.findall('(\d*)s',a))
    return h,m,s

for i in a:
    print get_time(i)
```

Output:

```
(1, 34, 2)
(1, 4, 0)
(0, 34, 2)
(0, 0, 34)
```

EDIT. I just saw, that you want date in seconds. You simply edit the **return** line in **get_time** function  into:

```
return h*3600+m*60+s
```

Output:

```
5642
3840
2042
34
```